# How to shrink a huge database on a webserver, so it can be developed on and run locally

Tags: database, sql, web-server

The size of the database on the webserver is on the order of 100s of GB, I can't run that locally on my PC. How do I shrink the database so I can test new features for the website?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This kind of data is called "fixtures" and you really **shouldn't** attempt to create them from a production DB. You should rather set up some test data that's sufficient for local environment work. Most popular frameworks provide an easy way to set up fixtures through e.g. YAML files.